# scan multiple pages using vba into word .docx

Tags: vba, scanning, multipage

Hi i was looking at other threads similar to this but they all seem to be for PDFs.  I have a macro that i need to run which calls up the scanner and scans docs into word365.  I found a working vba code online but it only allows for 1 page to be scanned even if multiples are in the ADF.  here is the code im currently using:

```vb
Sub Scan()
    'Requires a reference to Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Object Library
     Dim objCommonDialog As WIA.CommonDialog
     Dim objImage As WIA.ImageFile
     Dim strPath As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objCommonDialog = New WIA.CommonDialog
    Set objImage = objCommonDialog.ShowAcquireImage
    strPath = Environ("TEMP") & "\TempScan.jpg" ' set temporary file

    If Not objImage Is Nothing Then
    objImage.SaveFile strPath ' save into temporary file
    ' Insert in Word Document
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture strPath

    '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ' Insertion alternatives


    ' Insert in Excel worksheet
    'ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strPath).Select

    'Insert into Outlook message
    ' If ActiveInspector.IsWordMail And ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
    ' ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture strPath
    ' End If
    'End If
    '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Set objImage = Nothing
    End If
    If Not Dir(strPath) = vbNullString Then Kill strPath 'Remove the temporary file
    Set objCommonDialog = Nothing
    End Sub
```

I dont know what needs modified to have it prompt or even just automatically scan every page into the word365 doc.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

i have only tried this, i googled it for word 365 and couldnt find any good results.  the old simple code we used to use in office 2010 worked flawlessly but now in word365 it wont.

Comment: just to clarify.  Its veterinary software, when we check in a client we run a scan cmd via the software, this opens word and the macro would scan their check in sheet and the software adds it to that specific clients profile.   the scanner is a brother MF L5705DW ( i think) and the brother control center works perfectly fine, but for our veterinary software it has to be scanned thru word.   Is there a macro or vba that would open the brother control center and allow the scans to be added to the word doc?  better yet how to change the code to add or ask "scan another page"